# xls:apply-template on node selected from root

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to write and xsl transformation to create a html form from xs schema. Problem I've come across is when I am in template of an reference element and then I need to apply template of that element's definition which is in other branch of the element tree. Here is an example:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Root node -->
    <xsl:template match="//xs:element[@name='xmlRoot']">
        <form id="form">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:complexType/xs:sequence/*" />
        </form>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:group[@ref]">
        <!-- Here I need to find the referenced group -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:group[@name='{@ref}']" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:group[@name]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:sequence/*" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

And the schema that I want to transform:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="xmlRoot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="basic-info-group"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="basic-info-group">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

I start to match the templates from the schema for `xmlRoot` element, then match the group inside it and in group's first template I need to call the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath applying the second stage is messed up. To correct it, change

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:group[@name='{@ref}']" />
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:group[@name=current()/@ref]" />
```

Then it uses the second template in the first one.
Or you can use an absolute path like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/xs:schema/xs:group[@name=current()/@ref]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the attribute comparing. The selector with `//` at the beginning doesn't work anyway, becuase current element is the `xs:group` inside the `xmlRoot`. The full path work ok but I think there might be some cases where I won't know the full path.

Answer (score 0):

The `select="//xs:group[@name='{@ref}']"` should be `select="//xs:group[@name = current()/@ref]"` or use a key `<xsl:key name="group-ref" match="xs:group" use="@name"/>` and `select="key('group-ref', @ref)"`.